# nhibernate 3.2, how to map foreign key

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, s#arp

I am building my applicaiton using nhibernate 3.2 and s#arp lite framework.

### table "Stack" :

Id: int (PK)

Title: string

PostBy: int (FK, User table Id)

I am using automapping,  by convention its looking for UserID which does not exist.  I need to override this.

here's my code, it doesn't work, please help me to fix it.

```
internal class StackOverride : IOverride
{
    public void Override(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Class<Stack>(s =>
            {
                s.Property(x => x.PostBy, map => map.Column("PostBy"));
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally figure it out how to do it. here's the code.

```
   public void Override(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Class<Stack>(map => 
            map.ManyToOne(
                        x => x.PostBy, 
                        manyToOne => 
                                    {
                                        manyToOne.Column("PostBy");
                                    }));
    }
```